# Multlingual script does not redirect properly in the requested page

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working on multilingual script for a website which will contain 4 languages.
The script generates dynamic URLs as shown below:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?lang=es
http://www.example.com/index.php?lang=de
and so on...
```

Considering the need to have SEO friendly URLs  I have rewritten them in the .htaccess file like this:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^es/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

in order to display static URLs: http://www.example.com/es/es.html etc...

So far so good...
I also modified the PHP code as following:

Old code and new code:

```
foreach($langArray as $language){
echo "<a href='?lang=". $language ."'><img src='trad/flag_". 
$language .".png' /></a> ";
}


$langArray = $translate->getAllLanguages();
foreach($langArray as language){
echo "<a href='".$language .'/'.$language.".html'><img src='trad/flag_". 
$language .".png'   /></a> "; 
$langArray[$i] .".png' /></a> ";
}
```

If I cklick on one of the flags the link redirects on the desired page. 
For example:

```
www.example.com/es/es.html
```

If I clik on another flag, for istance German, the page redirects me on following page:
     **www.example.com/es/de/de.html** instead of **www.example.com/de/de.html**

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use a root-relative URL. This URL start with an `/`.

Example

`<a href="/de/de.html">`

or use your domain in the `href`

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/de/de.html">
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a classic error. You write a relative link (not starting with `/`). The browser interprets it relative as current page URL. If you are on a top level page (immediately under `/`, all is fine, but as soon as the current URL is deeper (one level or more) you get :

```
/old_url_begin/new_url
```

You have to use an absolute URL :

```
echo "<a href='/".$language .'/'.$language.".html'>
```

Comment: Hi Serge, I also used an absolute URL, but I get the same result.

Comment: @Daniel Please show how you write the `<a href=...>` for the link you click on

Comment: Here is the code:
    $langArray = $translate->getAllLanguages();
    foreach($langArray as $language){
    echo "<a href='/".$language .'/'.$language.".html'>
    <img src='Translate/flag_". $language .".png' /></a> ";
    }?>

Comment: @Daniel When you look at the source code in the browser you should then see something like `<a href="/de/de.html"><img src='Translat/flag_de.png/></a><a href="/es/es.html"><img src='Translat/flag_es.png/></a>`. Is it something like that ?

Comment: Hi Serge, I got it. Now the script is working fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Daniel : If it works for you, do not forget to accept an answer to notify other readers that you no longer need help for this question.